# Почему ошибкa: ORA-12838: невозможно прочитать/модифицировать объект после его модификации параллельным процессом

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Изучаю PL/SQL. Выдали задание, в котором нужно найти ошибки в анонимном блоке:

```
DECLARE
  l_Cnt_Del NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT --+ append
  INTO NAME_TABLE
  SELECT Cvm.*, Trunc(SYSDATE) Calc_Date 
  FROM NAME_TABLE1 Cvm;
  DELETE FROM NAME_TABLE Cvh
  WHERE Cvh.Calc_Date < Trunc(SYSDATE) - 14;
  l_Cnt_Del := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

> ORA-12838: невозможно прочитать/модифицировать объект после его модификации параллельным процессом
> ORA-06512: на  line 8

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

---

Запрос с таблицами на [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4e29135f7fa48ab703ec5ec17f76a21).

Comment: Функция `TRUNC(date)` принимает два параметра. Первый - что резать, второй - как. И если SYSDATE() в качестве первого параметра - нормально, то вот что там за хрень передаётся как второй параметр? PS. Забудьте о звёздах где-либо, кроме `COUNT(*)` - рано Вам ещё... перечисляйте пока что все поля поштучно. И в INSERT INTOб кстати, тоже.

Comment: Вставила код в вопросе, в том виде, каким он был в задании изначально. Удалю свой предыдущий коммент, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение

Comment: Хорошо, теперь и ошибка будет другая? Выполните и посмотрите. В прошлом коде delete был, а теперь куда он делся?

Comment: DELETE вернула))), извиняюсь, я три дня сижу с этим задание, голова уже не соображает. Выполнила код с добавлением атрибутов к NAME_TABLE(Cvm, Trunc(SYSDATE) Calc_Date. Выводится ошибка ORA-06550: Строка 5, столбец 45: PL/SQL: ORA-00917: отсутствует запятая

Comment: Теперь как в вопросе код рабочий, за исключением +append. Вам эту ошибку надо было найти?

Comment: Да, про +append я знаю, добавлю. Спасибо, до меня дошло

Comment: Или в этом случае +append не нужно использовать?

Comment: _Или в этом случае +append не нужно использовать?_. но я же не знаю, что вам нужно, полное задание вы не написали. Так как в вопросе +append работать не будет. В удалённом комментарии было - найти ошибки в коде.

Comment: Здорово, что вы поправили вопрос! Я ещё немного подредактировал, теперь выглядиит вообше отлично. Проверте, всё там так. Если ваша проблема теперь решена, то почитайте: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

В коде вопроса логическая ошибка, т.е. ошибка во время выполнения.
Без подсказки оптимизатору `+ append`, код рабочий.

С подсказкой `+ append` будет выполнена прямая вставка (*Direct Path*) и с ней связаны некоторые ограничения, про которые [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) сказано следующее:

> You can have multiple direct-path INSERT statements in a single transaction, with or without other DML statements. However, **after one DML statement alters a particular table**, partition, or index, **no other DML statement in the transaction can access that table**, partition, or index.

После прямой вставки в таблицу нельзя обращаться к этой таблице в этой же транзакции.

Другими словами, после прямой вставки надо завершить транзакцию до того, как выполнить следуюший DML с этой таблицей (в вопросе `DELETE FROM NAME_TABLE` в строке 8).

Посмотрите на воспроизводимом примере, как надо правильно сделать:

```
create table tab1 (id, name) as
    select rownum, 'name'||rownum from dual connect by level<100 
/
create table tab2 (id, name, calc_date) as
    select 1, 'name123', date'1970-01-01' from dual where 1=0
/
declare
    CntDel number;
    procedure copy is 
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        insert /*+ append */ into tab2
        select Cvm.*, Trunc (sysdate) calc_date from tab1 Cvm;
        commit;
    end;    
begin
    copy;
    delete from tab2 Cvh
    where Cvh.calc_date < Trunc (sysdate) - 14;
    CntDel := sql%rowcount;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

PS `pragma autonomous_transaction` служит, чтобы не зафиксировать полную транзакцию, т.е все те изменения, которые произошли до вызова анонимного блока.